# Unix Socket Error 14 in Clozure Common Lisp

Tags: sockets, common-lisp, ccl

I am trying to run hunchentoot on PPC64 linux , and it seems that there are something wrong with CCL's native socket api on this platform :

```
(T482:lisp/ccl/201908011326) # cat 4.lisp 
(WITH-OPEN-SOCKET (socket :LOCAL-PORT 6667 
                          :LOCAL-HOST "localhost" 
                          :CONNECT :PASSIVE 
                          :REUSE-ADDRESS t)
  (let ((stream (ACCEPT-CONNECTION socket :wait t)))
    (format stream "hello from server.~%")
    (finish-output stream)
    stream))

(T482:lisp/ccl/201908011326) # ./ccl-1.11/ppccl64 -I 0.img 
Welcome to Clozure Common Lisp Version 1.11  (LinuxPPC64)!  
CCL is developed and maintained by Clozure Associates. For more 
information
about CCL visit http://ccl.clozure.com.  To enquire about Clozure's 
Common Lisp
consulting services e-mail info@clozure.com or visit 
http://www.clozure.com.
? (load "4.lisp")
> Error: on #<CCL::LISTENER-SOCKET #x52001727E7C> : 
>        Bad address (error #14) during bind
> While executing: SOCKET-ERROR, in process listener(1).
> Type :POP to abort, :R for a list of available restarts.
> Type :? for other options.
1 >
```

Comment: silly question, perhaps, but are you sure `localhost` is defined in `/etc/hosts` …?

Comment: I am sure that localhost is defined in /etc/hosts , and I have tried many other ports ,  none of them is occupied by other programs.